# jQuery Circle Progress prevent the animation start from 0 if data updated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using jquery-circle-progress plugin.

The code is working perfectly. But now I put 1 button there to update the value of percentage.

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

As you can see below example, When I click the button then the circle progress will update the data but I want the animation is not reset from 0, just continue from current value to updated value.

Is it possible?

```js
let options = {
        startAngle: -1.55,
        size: 150,
        value: 0.85,
        fill: {gradient: ['#a445b2', '#fa4299']}
      }
      $(".circle .bar").circleProgress(options).on('circle-animation-progress',
      function(event, progress, stepValue){
        $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
});

$(".react .bar").circleProgress({
  value: 0.60
});

$('#add').on('click', function(){
  $(".react .bar").circleProgress({
  value: 0.80
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #53c68a, #8b67c4);
}
.wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper .card{
  background: #fff;
     width: calc(25% - 8px);
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper .card .circle{
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: default;
}
.card .circle .box,
.card .circle .box span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.card .circle .box{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.card .circle:hover .box{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.91);
}
.card .circle .box span,
.wrapper .card .text{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a445b2, #fa4299);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.circle .box span{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.card .circle:hover .box span{
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%) scale(1.09);
}
.card .text{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
@media(max-width: 753px){
  .wrapper{
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  .wrapper .card{
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 505px){
  .wrapper{
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .wrapper .card{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card react">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="box"><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">React JS</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just change the `circleProgress` function signature to receive a string and a number.

```js
$(".react .bar").circleProgress('value', 0.60);
 ...
$(".react .bar").circleProgress('value', 0.80);
```

Following the fourth example found in the [documentation](https://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/examples.js), in order to emulate dynamic value update, you must call the method passing two arguments, a string `'value'` then a real number ranging from 0 to 1 to go to based on the previous set value.

```js
let options = {
        startAngle: -1.55,
        size: 150,
        value: 0.85,
        fill: {gradient: ['#a445b2', '#fa4299']}
      }
      $(".circle .bar").circleProgress(options).on('circle-animation-progress',
      function(event, progress, stepValue){
       let precision = 1; // change here number of digits after .
       let num = (stepValue*100).toFixed(precision);
       $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(num) + "%");
});

$(".react .bar").circleProgress('value', 0.60);

$('#add').on('click', function(){
  $(".react .bar").circleProgress('value', 0.802);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #53c68a, #8b67c4);
}
.wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper .card{
  background: #fff;
     width: calc(25% - 8px);
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.wrapper .card .circle{
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: default;
}
.card .circle .box,
.card .circle .box span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.card .circle .box{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.card .circle:hover .box{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.91);
}
.card .circle .box span,
.wrapper .card .text{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a445b2, #fa4299);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.circle .box span{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.card .circle:hover .box span{
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%) scale(1.09);
}
.card .text{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
@media(max-width: 753px){
  .wrapper{
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  .wrapper .card{
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 505px){
  .wrapper{
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .wrapper .card{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card react">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="box"><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">React JS</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it works now. 1 question, can we change the percentage to be decimal? Example 80.2 %

Comment: Sure! Just change the precision. Check the edit, please.

Comment: Working perfect. Cheers

Comment: Hi, I have another similar question, could you please have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016948/jquery-javascript-counter-with-animation-always-reset-from-0-to-n-value