# jQuery/Javascript counter with animation always reset from 0 to N value

Tags: jquery, counter

I have these below counter js function. It's working OK.

But now when I try to add the new value to `$(".set")` to 30, the counter is reset from 0 until 30.

What I need is just continue the counter from the last state (25) to 30 (with animate) without reset the counter.

How to do the best way for this?

```js
$.fn.counter = function(){
  var $el = this;

  $el.prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $el.text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
      $el.text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
};

$(".set").counter();

$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".set").text(30);
  $(".set").counter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="set">25</div>

<button id="add">Add to 30</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue the animation adding another delay of custom duration, one option is to add a parameter `start` to the `counter` function to define the number it should begin counting.

```js
$.fn.counter = function(start){
  var $el = this;

  $el.prop('Counter',start).animate({
    Counter: $el.text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
      $el.text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
};

$(".set").counter(0);

$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".set").text(30);
  $(".set").counter(25);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="set">25</div>

<button id="add">Add to 30</div>
```

Now at any time you click the button, it will start counting from `0` to `25` within `4000` ms and it will continue from the last value up to `30` with another animation of the same duration.

Comment: Hi, how about if this `$(".set").counter(25);` is dynamic? It's not always 25.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You can pass any value you want